# How we can use httpclient, httpdelete, httpput in okhttp

Tags: android, api

I used org.apache.http library in api calls. but now i changed the org.apache.http library to okhttp library. org.apache.http library is not supporting in higher sdk versions. In org.apache.http library I used httpdelete, httpclient, httpput to call the api's. But in okhttp how to use these methods.

Advanced thanks and regards

Comment: `Request.Builder` has the builder methods `put()`, `post()`, and others too. To do PUT, POST, DELETE, etc. requests you should use them.

Comment: to add to the answer of @VladMatvienko answer... use the methods from Request.Builder. If you want to send some body content, all of them accept RequestBody objects where you can send a json or any other content supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source for `org.apache.http.client.methods.Http*` classes, you will see that each one is just a simple override for the `getMethod()` function along with constructor definitions.

```
@Override
public String getMethod() {
  return METHOD_NAME;
}
```

HttpClient does this for it's own internal API and to do checks such as `if (request instanceof HttpPut) { /* do the thing */ }`

#### How do I get the equivalent code in OkHttp?

OkHttp constructs instances of their classes using `Builder` classes. So to make a `PUT` request, you would use:

```
/* HttpClient */
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPut(/* Target URL */);

/* OkHttp */
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(/* Target URL */)
        .put(/* RequestBody instance (e.g. form content) */)
        .headers(/* Headers object */)
        .build());
```

The `Builder` class contains many "convenience" methods to make the common requests. These can be used in place of the `put()` method above.

```
get(), head(), post(RequestBody body), delete(RequestBody body), delete(), put(RequestBody body), patch(RequestBody body)
```

Alternatively, you can assign a method from a String using the `method(String method, RequestBody body)` function.

Most if not all OkHttp classes will use Builders. So your code won't be directly translatable.